# Python: Extract text from xml

Tags: python, xml

I have a Directory full of XML-files. I'd like to go through all files, extract the text in a new file and Name the new file like the meta-tag in the XML + a number.

Example:
All XML-files look like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<event><event id="9936070" origin="2008_01.xml"><meta/><text><original>Here is the text.</original>
</text><actors><actor><name>Enterprise</name><polarity>negativ implizit</polarity><centrality>zentral</centrality></actor></actors></event></event>
```

Now, I'd like to extract the text ("Here is the text.") and save it in a file called "Enterprise_2008_01.xml".
How is this possible? And, especially, how is it possible to consider all files and, according to circumstances, increase the last number (if there is another file with the tag "Enterprise" from 2008, the file-Name should be "Enterprise_2008_02.xml".
Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Comment: or just [ElementTree](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) which comes with python

Answer (score 0):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as eltre
path = 'C:/myfile.xml'
eTree = eltre.ElementTree()
eTree.parse(path)
elements = list(eTree.getroot())
for el in elements:
    print el.text
    #prints body
    print el.tag
    #prints elementName
    print el.attrib
    #prints attributes
    childElements = list(el)
    #gets children
```